# How to omit leading zeros in dates using Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

In .bib file I have my eventdate field (for @inproceedings entry) set like this:

```
eventdate={2012-08-02/2012-08-16}
```

Output looks now like this (using the [alldates=terse] option, with language 'finnish'):

```
02.-16.08.2012
```

Is it possible to format all dates (both date ranges and individual dates) so that the leading zeros are omitted:

```
2.-16.8.2012
```

That would follow the Finnish way of writing dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the options

```
[alldates=terse, datezeros=false]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was too easy :) Didn't catch that option when looking through the documentation.

Comment: The documentation,  I must admit, is… copious.

Comment: If you are interested in date formatting, have a look at 3.5 DEV and biber 2.6 DEV. These implement full EDTF level 0 and level 1 data/time parsing and output, including circa, uncertain and unspecified dates plus built in support for date eras (BCE/CE/BC/AD). Times are now parsed and supported for output too. All of this is also localised for things like era names, time parts (AM/PM) and separators etc.